# Javascript/Jquery returning tomorrows date, but skip Sundays

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I want to get tomorrows date, but if tomorrow is Sunday I want it to skip that date and return me the date after Sunday.

So if today is Fri 20/11/2020, I want js to return Sat 21/11/2020. But if I run the code tomorrow it should return me Mon 23/11/2020

How do I do this?

Comment: You advance the date by one day (easy to research, if you don’t know how), then you check what day of the week that is (also not hard to figure out, if you do a bit of _reading up_ on the `Date` object) - and if that is a Sunday, then you simply perform the first step a second time.

Answer (score 1):

```
let tomorrow = new Date();
if(new Date().getDay()==6){
   tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 2);
}else{
   tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
}
```

Comment: Option with less repeated code: `var date = new Date();
var adv = date.getDay()===6 ? 2 : 1;
date.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + adv);`

Comment: `let d = new Date(); d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1 + (d.getDay() == 6))`.